# I can't manage my brightness in newly installed ubuntu 17.10, how to do it?

Tags: brightness, tools

Laptop config:

- dell 7567
- i7 intel graphics + nvidia 1050ti

[image: laptop details]

I can't manage my brightness in newly installed ubuntu 17.10, all other functions are well except this brightness thing.
There is no option for it in setting as well.

Comment: Could you provide more information, like if you have installed any graphic drivers or if you have done any updates?

Comment: "sudo apt-get update" I did this only, I haven't manually installed any drivers.